# How can I access a Team Drive instead of personal Google Drive using PyDrive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, pydrive

I am trying to use PyDrive to programmatically list and then download files stored on a Team Drive that I can access in a browser. When I do this:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file_list = drive.ListFile(
    {
        'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false",
        'corpora': "teamDrive",
        'teamDriveId': <team drive ID>,
        'includeTeamDriveItems': "true",
        'supportsTeamDrives': "true"
    }
).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
    print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

I only get the list of files on my *personal* drive, not the team drive. What am I doing wrong?

**Note1:** I got the `<team drive ID>` by opening the Team Drive (the root folder) in the browser and copying everything after "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/"

**Note2:** Browser pops up at `drive.ListFile` and gives `Authentication successful.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a team drive, files can only have one parent folder and a team drive file's parent is never root.

I was able to use the drive id again instead of root to get this to work, but I also used boolean values for true instead of strings:

```
drive.ListFile({'q':"'<Team_Drive_Id_Or_Folder_Id>' in parents and trashed=false", 'corpora': 'teamDrive', 'teamDriveId': '<Team_Drive_Id>', 'includeTeamDriveItems': True, 'supportsTeamDrives': True}).GetList()
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now I need to figure out how to download those files. Can't seem to do it with team drive files, only with files in my drive...

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me as well even with the update to Shared drives.

Comment: How do I get Team_Drive_Id value?

Comment: This still works with the current version of shared drives in Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `pydrive2` which supports this natively.