# How to read files in multiple folders under Shared Google Drive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, pydrive

Is it possible to get files inside Google Shared Drive? PyDrive is able to iterate over files in MyDrive but not Shared Drive. The files are inside multiple folders:

`Department -> PDF -> MONTH YEAR -> DATE -> DAILY REPORT.pdf`

Codes tried but both returned "To look folder level":

```
# #Make GoogleDrive instance with Authenticated GoogleAuth instance
# drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
f = drive.ListFile({"q": "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false}).GetList()

for folder in f:
    print(folder['title'], folder['id'])
```

To look file level:

```
# # Auto-iterate through all files that matches this query
# file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format(folder_id)}).GetList()
# # print(file_list)
# for file1 in file_list:
#   print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a similar case. 
It works now using the codes:

```
# file_list =  drive.ListFile({'q':"'<Team_Drive_Id_Or_Folder_Id>' in parents and trashed=false", 'corpora': 'teamDrive', 'teamDriveId': '<Team_Drive_Id>', 'includeTeamDriveItems': True, 'supportsTeamDrives': True}).GetList()
```

[How can I access a Team Drive instead of personal Google Drive using PyDrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729923/how-can-i-access-a-team-drive-instead-of-personal-google-drive-using-pydrive)